# Uninstall rabbitmq and reinstall K8S via same bitnami helm script pods fail to start

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I've been prototyping K8S and RabbitMQ on a vanilla on-premise K8S instance (i.e. not AWS/Azure). I installed RabbitMQ via the Bitnami Helm script and it worked first time without any issues. I then decided to remove the deployment (via helm), add some community plug-ins and then re-install via the same Helm script.

All credentials were the same between both installs.

Now, K8S will not start the pod :(

The K8S reported error from the pod is:

```
Readiness probe failed: Error: Failed to connect and authenticate to rabbit@rabbitmq-headless.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
```

I've noticed that the external IP granted to the service (via MetalLB) is different but I think the pod name is the same.

I think that the helm remove didn't clean up some internal K8S DNS entries.... but I'm still learning K8S so I'm not sure where to look to check this, and to find and remove anything hanging around.

The pod log doesn't say anything of use:

```
rabbitmq 22:12:35.68 
rabbitmq 22:12:35.68 Welcome to the Bitnami rabbitmq container
rabbitmq 22:12:35.68 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq
rabbitmq 22:12:35.69 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq/issues
rabbitmq 22:12:35.69 
rabbitmq 22:12:35.69 INFO  ==> ** Starting RabbitMQ setup **
rabbitmq 22:12:35.71 INFO  ==> Validating settings in RABBITMQ_* env vars..
rabbitmq 22:12:35.74 INFO  ==> Initializing RabbitMQ...
```

I left this for a while and it never changed.

I then tried to reinstall without the addition plug-in (it was the delayed message plug in).

This seemed to go better but the pods still will not start (same reason). In this case the pod log indicates some movement

```
rabbitmq 22:37:46.70 
rabbitmq 22:37:46.71 Welcome to the Bitnami rabbitmq container
rabbitmq 22:37:46.71 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq
rabbitmq 22:37:46.71 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq/issues
rabbitmq 22:37:46.71 
rabbitmq 22:37:46.72 INFO  ==> ** Starting RabbitMQ setup **
rabbitmq 22:37:46.74 INFO  ==> Validating settings in RABBITMQ_* env vars..
rabbitmq 22:37:46.76 INFO  ==> Initializing RabbitMQ...
rabbitmq 22:37:46.80 INFO  ==> Persisted data detected. Restoring...
rabbitmq 22:37:46.81 INFO  ==> ** RabbitMQ setup finished! **

rabbitmq 22:37:46.83 INFO  ==> ** Starting RabbitMQ **
Configuring logger redirection
2021-01-25 22:38:02.925 [debug] <0.286.0> Lager installed handler error_logger_lager_h into error_logger
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.289.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into error_logger_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.292.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.295.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_channel_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.319.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_ra_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.322.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_shovel_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.298.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_connection_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.325.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_upgrade_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.301.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_feature_flags_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.954 [debug] <0.304.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_federation_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.955 [debug] <0.307.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_ldap_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.955 [debug] <0.310.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_mirroring_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.955 [debug] <0.313.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_prelaunch_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.955 [debug] <0.316.0> Lager installed handler lager_forwarder_backend into rabbit_log_queue_lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:02.972 [info] <0.44.0> Application lager started on node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-headless.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local'
2021-01-25 22:38:03.291 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia started on node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-headless.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local'
2021-01-25 22:38:03.292 [info] <0.270.0> 
 Starting RabbitMQ 3.8.9 on Erlang 22.3
 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
 Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.8.9
  ##  ##
  ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2020 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
  ######  ##
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  Doc guides: https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
  Support:    https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
  Tutorials:  https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
  Monitoring: https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html

  Logs: <stdout>

  Config file(s): /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

  Starting broker...2021-01-25 22:38:03.295 [info] <0.270.0> 
 node           : rabbit@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-headless.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
 home dir       : /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/.rabbitmq
 config file(s) : /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
 cookie hash    : ENSyEjlycK3XumHZ0m5A3g==
 log(s)         : <stdout>
 database dir   : /bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-headless.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
2021-01-25 22:38:03.425 [debug] <0.282.0> Lager installed handler lager_backend_throttle into lager_event
2021-01-25 22:38:07.395 [info] <0.270.0> Running boot step pre_boot defined by app rabbit
2021-01-25 22:38:07.395 [info] <0.270.0> Running boot step rabbit_core_metrics defined by app rabbit
2021-01-25 22:38:07.396 [info] <0.270.0> Running boot step rabbit_alarm defined by app rabbit
2021-01-25 22:38:07.402 [info] <0.351.0> Memory high watermark set to 1574 MiB (1650966528 bytes) of 3936 MiB (4127416320 bytes) total
2021-01-25 22:38:07.409 [info] <0.353.0> Enabling free disk space monitoring
2021-01-25 22:38:07.409 [info] <0.353.0> Disk free limit set to 50MB
2021-01-25 22:38:07.415 [info] <0.270.0> Running boot step code_server_cache defined by app rabbit
2021-01-25 22:38:07.415 [info] <0.270.0> Running boot step file_handle_cache defined by app rabbit
2021-01-25 22:38:07.416 [info] <0.356.0> Limiting to approx 1048479 file handles (943629 sockets)
2021-01-25 22:38:07.416 [info] <0.357.0> FHC read buffering:  OFF
2021-01-25 22:38:07.416 [info] <0.357.0> FHC write buffering: ON
2021-01-25 22:38:07.417 [info] <0.270.0> Running boot step worker_pool defined by app rabbit
2021-01-25 22:38:07.417 [info] <0.344.0> Will use 2 processes for default worker pool
2021-01-25 22:38:07.417 [info] <0.344.0> Starting worker pool 'worker_pool' with 2 processes in it
2021-01-25 22:38:07.418 [info] <0.270.0> Running boot step database defined by app rabbit
2021-01-25 22:38:07.419 [info] <0.270.0> Node database directory at /bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq-headless.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local is empty. Assuming we need to join an existing cluster or initialise from scratch...
2021-01-25 22:38:07.419 [info] <0.270.0> Configured peer discovery backend: rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
2021-01-25 22:38:07.438 [info] <0.270.0> Will try to lock with peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
2021-01-25 22:38:07.438 [info] <0.270.0> Peer discovery backend does not support locking, falling back to randomized delay
2021-01-25 22:38:07.439 [info] <0.270.0> Peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s supports registration.
2021-01-25 22:38:07.439 [info] <0.270.0> Will wait for 90 milliseconds before proceeding with registration...
2021-01-25 22:38:09.789 [error] <0.270.0> Failed to fetch a list of nodes from Kubernetes API: {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},
                 {inet,[inet],timeout}]}
2021-01-25 22:38:12.043 [error] <0.270.0> Peer discovery returned an error: "{failed_connect,[{to_address,{\"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local\",443}},\n                 {inet,[inet],timeout}]}". Will retry after a delay of 500 ms, 9 retries left...
2021-01-25 22:38:14.796 [error] <0.270.0> Failed to fetch a list of nodes from Kubernetes API: {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},
                 {inet,[inet],timeout}]}
2021-01-25 22:38:17.050 [error] <0.270.0> Peer discovery returned an error: "{failed_connect,[{to_address,{\"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local\",443}},\n                 {inet,[inet],timeout}]}". Will retry after a delay of 500 ms, 8 retries left...
2021-01-25 22:38:19.803 [error] <0.270.0> Failed to fetch a list of nodes from Kubernetes API: {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},
                 {inet,[inet],timeout}]}
2021-01-25 22:38:22.056 [error] <0.270.0> Peer discovery returned an error: "{failed_connect,[{to_address,{\"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local\",443}},\n                 {inet,[inet],timeout}]}". Will retry after a delay of 500 ms, 7 retries left...
2021-01-25 22:38:24.812 [error] <0.270.0> Failed to fetch a list of nodes from Kubernetes API: {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},                 {inet,[inet],timeout}]}
```

The helm command for the plugin was:

```
helm install rabbitmq bitnami/rabbitmq -n rabbitmq --set 
metrics.enabled=true,auth.username=admin,auth.password=xxxxxxxxxx,service.type=LoadBalancer,communityPlugins=https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/3.8.9/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.8.9-0199d11c.ez,extraPlugins=rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange,replicaCount=1,metrics.serviceMonitor.enabled=true
```

The one without the plug in:

```
helm install rabbitmq bitnami/rabbitmq -n rabbitmq --set 
metrics.enabled=true,auth.username=admin,auth.password=xxxxxxxxxx,service.type=LoadBalancer
```

Running on K8S 1.18.3

Comment: You are using `Minikube` or `Kubeadm`? Which exactly chart you have used and which was your helm command to deploy?  What additional plugin you used? What k8s version are you using?

Comment: This is a "proper" K8S install (not minikube). Version is 1.18.3. The Bitnami script is automatic (I think?) from https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq/

updated with additional info

Comment: Additional info: If I run "kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup rabbitmq-headless.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local" AFTER rabbit has been uninstalled then it still resolves to an IP address. So it looks like CoreDNS hasn't been cleaned up after uninstall?

Can I edit the underlying files for CoreDNS?

Comment: Hmm. it appears that if I leave this several days and try the process again, it clears itself....

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when I added another node to the cluster and rabbitmq got deployed to the new node.

I have killed my coredns pod because I suspected dns cache issues.

After the coredns pod restarted, the rabbitmq pod started as usual